# How disable Docker swap for Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows-10, ram, swapfile

A lot of answers lead to the `docker run` command and the `--memory-swap` parameter. But how to do this once for all containers? There are Windows settings, but the swap parameter cannot be set to less than 512 Mb.

[image]

Comment: you can set that per container basis `--memory-swap=0m`

Comment: With what command? `docker run` is not a solution for me

Comment: it is available in compose also https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources

Comment: Do mean `memswap_limit`? Can it be set for all containers in one place in `docker-compose` file?

Comment: no , I think for each service in the compose